# Does a "chirp"-like generalization of the Gabor or Morlet wavelets definitions exist in the lit somewhere?

Tags: wavelet, gaussian, time-frequency, reference-request

[I have asked this at the Math SE also.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2759726/does-a-chirp-like-generalization-of-the-gabor-or-morlet-wavelets-definitions-e)

Predicating this on the definition of the continuous Fourier Transform preferred by most electrical engineers:

$$ X(f) \triangleq \mathscr{F} \Big\{ x(t) \Big\} \triangleq \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x(t) \, e^{-i 2 \pi f t} \ \mathrm{d}t $$

and inverse:

$$ x(t) \triangleq \mathscr{F}^{-1} \Big\{ X(f) \Big\} = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} X(f) \, e^{+i 2 \pi f t} \ \mathrm{d}f $$

Even with different signs on $i$, the elegant symmetry between the forward transform and inverse should be clear.  And it makes remembering the Duality property, Parseval's theorem easy:

If $X(f) = \mathscr{F} \Big\{ x(t) \Big\}$, then $x(-f) = \mathscr{F} \Big\{ X(t) \Big\}$.

$$  X(0) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x(t) \ \mathrm{d}t $$

$$  x(0) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} X(f) \ \mathrm{d}f $$

$$ \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \Big| x(t) \Big|^2 \ \mathrm{d}t = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \Big| X(f) \Big|^2 \ \mathrm{d}f$$

**NO** nasty asymmetrical scaling factors to worry about!!  (Just remember the $2\pi$ in the exponent.)  This is why EE's like this definition of the Fourier Transform.

Given this definition, then the Fourier transform of the gaussian function (exponent scaled as shown) is itself:

$$ \mathscr{F} \Big\{ e^{- \pi t^2} \Big\} = e^{- \pi f^2} $$

---

So, harmonizing the parameters and symbols, the normalized Gabor "mother wavelet" (with this parameter $\mathcal{F}$) is simply a complex sinusoid with a gaussian "window" or "envelope":

$$\begin{align}
 w(t) &\triangleq e^{-\pi t^2} \, e^{i 2 \pi \mathcal{F} t } \\
      &= e^{\pi (i\mathcal{F})^2} \left(e^{-\pi t^2} \, e^{i 2 \pi \mathcal{F} t } e^{-\pi (i\mathcal{F})^2} \right)  \\
      &= e^{-\pi \mathcal{F}^2} e^{-\pi (t-i\mathcal{F})^2} \\
\end{align}$$

The Fourier Transform isn't too hard to get:

$$ W(f) = e^{- \pi (f-\mathcal{F})^2} $$

My question is, in the literature, has this been generalized a little more and does this have a name?  (Like where can I read about it?)

$$\begin{align}
 w(t) &\triangleq e^{-\pi t^2} \, e^{i \pi \beta t^2} \, e^{i 2 \pi \mathcal{F} t } \\
      &= e^{-\pi (1 - i\beta) t^2}  e^{i 2 \pi \mathcal{F} t } \\
      &= e^{-\pi (\sqrt{1 - i\beta} \, t)^2}  e^{i 2 \pi \mathcal{F} t } \\
      &= e^{-\pi \mathcal{F}^2} e^{-\pi (\sqrt{1 - i\beta} \, t - i\mathcal{F})^2} \\
\end{align}$$

This makes this windowed sinusoid, a windowed *"chirp"* function.  We need both the $\beta$ parameter and the $\mathcal{F}$ parameter because the scaling on the width of the window is still normalized to 1.

I believe the Fourier Transform is

$$ W(f) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - i\beta}} \, e^{- \pi (f-\mathcal{F})^2/(1 - i\beta)} $$

This can be generalized one step further by putting in an exponential *"ramp"* parameter $\lambda$

$$\begin{align}
 w(t) &\triangleq e^{-\pi t^2} \, e^{i \pi \beta t^2} \, e^{i 2 \pi \mathcal{F} t } e^{2 \pi \lambda t } \\
      &= e^{-\pi (1 - i\beta) t^2}  e^{i 2 \pi (\mathcal{F}-i\lambda) t } \\
      &= e^{-\pi (\sqrt{1 - i\beta} \, t)^2}  e^{i 2 \pi (\mathcal{F}-i\lambda) t } \\
      &= e^{-\pi \mathcal{F}^2} e^{-\pi (\sqrt{1 - i\beta} \, t - i(\mathcal{F}-i\lambda))^2} \\
      &= e^{-\pi \mathcal{F}^2} e^{-\pi (\sqrt{1 - i\beta} \, t - i\mathcal{F}-\lambda))^2} \\
\end{align}$$

And it looks like the Fourier Transform is

$$ W(f) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - i\beta}} \, e^{- \pi (f-\mathcal{F}+i\lambda)^2/(1 - i\beta)} $$

Does this generalization exist in the lit somewhere and, if so, can I read about it without a pay-wall?

---

Also, it appears to me that, in general, we can say that

$$ \mathscr{F} \Big\{ e^{a t^2 + b t + c} \Big\} = e^{A f^2 + B f + C} $$

where the constants $A$, $B$, and $C$ can be explicitly mapped from $a$, $b$, and $c$. It appears to me that the mapping is:

$$\begin{align}
A &= \frac{\pi^2}{a} \\
B &= i \frac{\pi b}{a} \\
C &= c - \frac{b^2}{4a} - \tfrac{1}{2}\log\left(-\frac{a}{\pi}\right) \\
\end{align}$$

and the inverse mapping (which should be self-similar) is:

$$\begin{align}
a &= \frac{\pi^2}{A} \\
b &= -i \frac{\pi B}{A} \\
c &= C - \frac{B^2}{4A} - \tfrac{1}{2}\log\left(-\frac{A}{\pi}\right) \\
\end{align}$$

Looks like $\Re\{a\}<0$ and $\Re\{A\}<0$ for the integrals to converge and for the $\log(\cdot)$ to be real and finite in the mapping.

This appears to be true for quadratics in the exponent.  Is it also true for higher-order polynomials in the exponent?  Does this also exist in the lit somewhere?

Comment: Chirplet transform maybe?

Comment: yup @geometrikal.  that's what the math guys told me.  it funny but i hadn't heard the term *"chirplet"* before this.

Comment: _"the normalized Gabor"_ -> _"the simplified normalized Gabor"_. [Missing](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Morlet_wavelet) mean-corrective term.

Answer (score 1):

You've re-invented chirplets:

[image]

from

- [The Chirplet Transform: A Generalization of Gabor's Logon Transform](http://wearcam.org/chirplet/vi91/index.htm) (the heck is "Logon Transform"?) from Wiki's first reference in [Chirplet transform](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Chirplet_transform) -- and there's also
- [Adaptive Chirplet Representation of Signals on Time-Frequency Plane](https://sci-hub.st/10.1049/el:19910723), brought to you free by Russian pirates

This is identical to your second $w(t)$ (minus parameterization formulation), but not third, which introduces asymmetric windowing. So, I changed the notation $w(t)$ I dislike in the third $w(t)$ into

$$
w(t) \triangleq e^{-\pi t^2} \, e^{i \pi \beta t^2} \, e^{i 2 \pi \xi t } e^{2 \pi \gamma t }
$$

$\xi$ because the other guy looks like Fourier transform, and $\gamma$ because the other guy won't dine with a snake. Another problem is that, you claim the function's unity-normed, while it's not, and the Fourier transform also fails to center in time domain. It's also not zero-mean, so not "Gabor" but "simplified Gabor", but as long as we avoid certain mother wavelet parameters, we're okay. Except not quite because we'll still get fucked up by [discretization](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/78551/50076) for yet more params.

Fixing all these problems manually except extrema discretization, I used the snake to generate a filterbank:

[image]

That SSQ doesn't get botched up means we're doing good with time-domain phase. More examples:

[image]

Chirpy chirp slopes are working as intended. The most photogenic time-domain rampirplet I could make is below, but its filterbank sucks:

[image]

Now let's take some non-padded CWTs with circular cross-correlation:

[image]

That this looks like a normal CWT blows my mind, until I think a little. Now let's check stuff with interferences, with more wavelets, and vs normal Morlet CWT:

[image]

whatever the blasted thing on the left is, assymetry is working. It's certainly curious to check WGN:

[image]

Don't ask, I don't know.

It'd be interesting to inspect more asymmetric parameterizations, but discretization is a pain and I didn't bother. Note that here, per assymetry, the precise definition of CWT via cross-correlation rather than convolution matters, otherwise we'd see the slope trends reversed; sharply resolved features are positively sloped, same as the wavelet.

If you seek a head honcho generalization, consult [Generalized Morse Wavelets](https://overlordgolddragon.github.io/generalized-morse-wavelets/). Its default $\gamma=3$ is very Morlet-like. You can cite this answer as

> John Muradeli, 2023. "Chirp"-like generalization of the Gabor or Morlet wavelets. URL: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/87859/50076

#### Code, just the wavelets

I reckon some Fortran blokes never try to run Python cause who wants snake on their computer. Well we've got [snake in the cloud](https://replit.com/@OverLordGoldDra/rampirplets#main.py).

```py
# https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/48876/50076
import numpy as np
from numpy.fft import fft, ifft, ifftshift
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def W(f, xi=12, gamma=5, beta=5):
    K = 1/np.sqrt(1 - 1j*beta)
    exp = np.exp(-np.pi*(f - xi + 1j*gamma)**2 / (1 - 1j*beta))
    return K * exp

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, layout='constrained')
psis = []
for mult in np.logspace(np.log10(4), np.log10(2000), 100):
    f = np.linspace(0, 15, 4096*8)*mult
    pf = W(f, xi=1)
    pf /= abs(pf).max()
    pt = ifft(pf)
    pt = np.roll(pt, -np.argmax(pt))
    pf = fft(pt)
    axes[0].plot(abs(pf))
    psis.append(pf)

pt = ifftshift(ifft(psis[40]))
N = len(pt)
axes[1].plot(pt.real)
axes[1].plot(pt.imag)
axes[1].plot(abs(pt), color='k', linestyle='--')
axes[1].set_xlim(N//2-1000, N//2+1000)
axes[1].set_yticks([])
plt.show()
```