# Why is CWT implemented with FFT convolution?

Tags: discrete-signals, dft, convolution, wavelet, cwt

Some implementations generate wavelets in frequency domain.

1. Besides speed per FFT convolution, is there any reason?
2. All wavelets will be sampled at same length - 100,000 samples even for those having time-domain support of 28; why?
3. Implementations will left-right pad, so that original is centered - whereas in FFT convolution we right-pad. Is this still convolution, or  is it "alternative convolution", and why not right-pad?

Comment: I have more implementation analysis but rather not scare away answers; whatever I have doesn't explain why any of it is done and how it achieves 'better' results.

Comment: well, normally, the accepted mathematics is that the Fourier Transform is **bijective** or **one-to-one** with no unmapped *"holes"*.  So knowing $x(t) \quad \forall t$ or knowing $X(f) \triangleq \mathscr{F} \{ x(t) \} \quad \forall f$ are either sufficient as a complete description.  if you were specified ***both*** $x(t)$ ***and*** $X(f)$, they better be exactly consistent with each other, otherwise you will have more problems.

Comment: May not be worth writing a Q&A on boundary stuff, so I went with the other one. This time I'm nowhere near an answer, and may just ditch looking as it's probably some advanced math derivations. Answers are welcome.

Comment: O, this whole zero-padding thing as about **one** thing.  it's because of the inherent periodicity of the DFT in a world where life is not necessarily circular.  it's about how to use this circular tool do a linear task.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson This doesn't really tell me much - I invoke zero padding for its similarities with this method which may hint at an answer. Both extend then trim, apparently interpolating input spectra in the process.

Comment: NOTICE: Registered users may submit articles to be announced by arXiv. Submissions to arXiv are subject to a moderation process that classifies material as topical to the subject area and has scholarly value. Material **is not peer-reviewed by arXiv** -the content of arXiv **submissions are wholly the responsibility of the submitter and are presented “as is” without any warranty or guarantee**. By hosting works and other materials on this site, arXiv, Cornell University, and their agents do not in any way convey implied approval of the assumptions, methods, results, or conclusions of the work.

Comment: You should post your answer here and mark it. That's the right thing to do.

Comment: @Royi It's also time consuming and unrewarding with this network's upvote phobia. (especially toward me I'd add)

Comment: I will +1 you. I think many more will. You posted asking someone else to dedicate time, the fair thing to do is post yours.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson You weren't wrong; I had to realize "time aliasing" is simply circular overlap-add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is *wavelet design*. In brief, sampling in frequency domain offers precise control over certain desired filtering properties and is often subject to less discretization error.

#### Discretization error: smoothness

Which is easier to misrepresent with uniform sampling?

[image]

Left is a Morlet of high center frequency, right its Fourier transform. We can imagine, a slight mis-step on left may severely misrepresent the waveform. To see this in action, we push the center frequency near Nyquist:

[image]

with black lines at sampling positions. Changing the positions a bit...

[image]

A drastic change. It's unlikely we'd spot the difference in sampling positions without close inspection; all that changed is `endpoint=False -> True`. Alt perspective:

[image]

#### Filter control

##### Analyticity

Some applications demand strict analyticity (negative frequencies zero), and Morlet is pseudo-analytic: it leaks into negatives when near DC or Nyquist. A closed form time-domain expression for a strictly analytic Morlet wavelet *does not exist*; it is derived uniquely by *setting* negatives to zero and taking `ifft`.

##### Sparsity, redundancy

A filterbank's redundancy is controlled by the *overlap* of its frequency-domain waveforms:

[image]

Left is low redundancy, right is high. Low redundancy is desired for classification, high for temporal localization. There's additionally an aggregate indicator of information flow in frequency domain that can inform filterbank corrections - Littlewood-Paley sum (see "Energy analysis" here).

There aren't such measures in time domain.

##### Inversion

There's no indication of whether the CWT will be invertible directly in time domain: we require that the filters *tile the entire frequency axis*. If some frequencies receive no coverage, they're lost completely.

##### Subsampling

Unaliased subsampling by a factor of `k` requires that there are no non-zero
frequencies above `0.5/k` of sampling rate. Again no time-domain indication.

##### Disadvantage

For time-domain sampling, discretization error is greatest for highest frequencies - for freq-domain sampling, it's the reverse: we may end up with 1 sample to describe the entire wavelet, which is a common pitfall (it's a pure sine). Lower frequencies are better generated in time domain; further details [here](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/ssqueezepy/issues/29#issuecomment-833405901).

#### PyWavelets, Scipy

Have ill-designed filters; if we plot them in frequency domain, bandpassing near Nyquist leaks frequencies near DC, along other problems. I've not plotted them but [this post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/70643/50076) proves it.

**Update**: revisiting this with more experience, I find that PyWavelets' wavelet generation is, put bluntly, catastrophic, and `pywt.cwt` should be simply avoided. `scipy` with `morlet2` isn't terrible if we just want modulus and avoid frequencies near DC and Nyquist.

#### Alternative convolution?

Nothing such here; it's circular convolution. We guarantee equivalence with linear convolution by ensuring that "left doesn't draw from right", i.e. a wavelet's temporal support is sufficiently small ([further discussion](https://github.com/kymatio/kymatio/pull/734)). Using boxcar for clarity to denote temporal support:

[image]

The reason for left-right padding is programming convenience; various non-zero schemes, like `reflect`, are easier implemented. The resulting convolution is *exactly* the same as right padding, left padding, or any other arbitrary shift - it's inherent in circularity of DFT.

#### Why all same length?

Programmatic convenience and speed. However, latter can be greatly improved with overlap-add convolutions - at significant expense of former. Another reason is to have the same "reference frame" for designing frequency tiling - but the wavelets can be trimmed afterwards while preserving said tiling.

Comment: I like your Q & A posts. You add real valuable knowledge here.