# Weird Noise arises on the small scales: one question about the fast CWT algorithm implemented in real space

Tags: python, wavelet, algorithms, numpy, cwt

**Background:**

I am learning an interesting Fast CWT algorithm(PPCWT) by reading [this paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/9001739) published in 2019. The algorithm is summarized as below. The continuous wavelet transform of a signal can be calculated efficiently according to the last row of Eq.(1.4). To test this algorithm, I write a Cython module `ppCWT_cymod.pyx`, which is shown below the image.
[image]

```
#ppCWT_cymod.pyx
import sys
import math
import numpy as np
import cython
cimport numpy as np
from libc.math cimport ceil, floor, sqrt, log, round, abs, exp

# Second derivative of Gaussian-derived wavelet
def d3GDWdx3( scale, pos ):
    x  = scale*pos
    s3 = scale**3
    p1 = s3*np.exp(-(x/2.0)**2)*x*(60.0-20.0*x**2+x**4)
    p2 = 32.0*np.sqrt(np.pi)
    return p1/p2

# Compute the Bj
def BjCoeff( freqs, Ls, N, wavelet_name="gdw", half_support=13.0, Nums=46 ):
    Dx = Ls/float(N)
    # Choose a special wavelet function
    GDW_set = {"gdw", "GDW", "Gaussian-derived wavelet", "Gaussian derived wavelet"}
    if wavelet_name in GDW_set:
        scales = Dx*freqs*2.0/np.sqrt(5.0)
        d3psi  = d3GDWdx3
        alpha  = half_support
        J      = Nums
    else:
        sys.exit("There is no wavelet function called " + wavelet_name)

    gamma  = np.linspace(-alpha,alpha,num=J+1,endpoint=True, dtype=np.float64)

    pos    = (gamma[1:]+gamma[:-1])/2.0
    ss, pp = np.meshgrid(scales,pos,indexing="ij")
    Bcoeffs= np.zeros( (len(scales),len(gamma)), dtype=np.float64)

    Bcoeffs[:,0]    = d3psi( scales, pos[0]/scales )
    Bcoeffs[:,-1]   = -d3psi( scales, pos[-1]/scales )
    Bcoeffs[:,1:-1] = d3psi( ss[:,1:], pp[:,1:]/ss[:,1:] )-d3psi( ss[:,1:], pp[:,0:-1]/ss[:,1:] )
    return gamma, Bcoeffs

# 4th-order B-spline function
cdef bspline4th( double var ):
    cdef double y
    cdef double x = abs(var)
    
    if (x<=0.5):
        y = 115.0/192.0-5.0*x**2/8.0+x**4/4.0
    elif ((x>0.5)&(x<=1.5)):
        y = (55.0+20.0*x-120.0*x**2+80.0*x**3-16.0*x**4)/96.0
    elif ((x>1.5)&(x<=2.5)):
        y = (5.0-2.0*x)**4/384.0
    elif (x>2.5):
        y = 0.0
    return y

#5th-order B-spline function
cdef bspline5th( double var ):
    cdef double y
    cdef double x = abs(var)
    if (x<=1.0):
        y = (33.0-30.0*x**2+15.0*x**4-5.0*x**5)/60.0
    elif ((x>1.0)&(x<=2.0)):
        y = (51.0+75.0*x-210.0*x**2+150.0*x**3-45.0*x**4+5.0*x**5)/120.0
    elif ((x>2.0)&(x<=3.0)):
        y = -(x-3.0)**5/120.0
    elif (x>3.0):
        y = 0.0
    return y

#6th-order B-spline function
cdef bspline6th( double var ):
    cdef double y
    cdef double x = abs(var)
    if (x<=0.5):
        y = (5887.0-4620.0*x**2+1680.0*x**4-320.0*x**6)/11520.0
    elif ((x>0.5)&(x<=1.5)):
        y = (23583.0-420.0*x-16380.0*x**2-5600.0*x**3+15120.0*x**4-\
            6720.0*x**5+960.0*x**6)/46080.0
    elif ((x>1.5)&(x<=2.5)):
        y = (4137.0+30408.0*x-59220.0*x**2+42560.0*x**3-\
            15120.0*x**4+2688.0*x**5-192.0*x**6)/23040.0
    elif ((x>2.5)&(x<=3.5)):
        y = (7.0-2.0*x)**6/46080.0
    elif (x>3.5):
        y = 0.0
    return y

#7th-order B-spline function
cdef bspline7th( double var ):
    cdef double y
    cdef double x = abs(var)
    if (x<=1.0):
        y = 151.0/315.0 - x**2/3.0+x**4/9.0-x**6/36.0+x**7/144.0
    elif ((x>1.0)&(x<=2.0)):
        y = (2472.0-392.0*x-504.0*x**2-1960.0*x**3+2520.0*x**4-\
             1176.0*x**5+252.0*x**6-21*x**7)/5040.0
    elif ((x>2.0)&(x<=3.0)):
        y = (-1112.0+12152.0*x-19320.0*x**2+13720.0*x**3-5320.0*x**4+\
            1176.0*x**5-140.0*x**6+7.0*x**7)/5040.0
    elif ((x>3.0)&(x<=4.0)):
        y = -(x-4.0)**7/5040.0
    elif (x>4.0):
        y = 0.0
    return y

# Interpolation coefficients of the signal based on 3rd-order B-spline
# This signal satisfy the zero boundary condition
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.cdivision(True)
cdef InterpCoeffs( np.ndarray[double,ndim=1] signal ):

    cc_plus  = np.zeros_like(signal, dtype=np.double) 
    cc_minus = np.zeros_like(signal, dtype=np.double)

    cdef int    k
    cdef int    N       = len(signal)
    cdef double z1      = -2.0 + sqrt(3.0)
    cdef double z1_2    = z1**2
    cdef int    N_z1    = -<int>( round(60*log(10) / log(abs(z1))) )
    cdef double[:] y_input = signal
    cdef double[:] c_plus  = cc_plus
    cdef double[:] c_minus = cc_minus

    # Compute c_plus
    c_plus[0] = y_input[0]
    for k in range(1,N):
        c_plus[k] = y_input[k] + z1*c_plus[k-1]
    # Compute c_minus
    z1_powers    = z1_2**( np.arange(1, N_z1+1) )
    c_minus[N-1] = -6.0*( y_input[N-1]/z1 + c_plus[N-2] )*np.sum( z1_powers )
    for k in range(N-2,-1,-1):
        c_minus[k] = z1*( c_minus[k+1] - 6.0*c_plus[k] )
    c_minus_left  = c_minus[0]*( z1**np.arange(6,0,-1) )
    c_minus_right = -6.0*c_plus[N-1]*np.sum( z1_powers )*np.array([1.0, z1])
    ck            = np.concatenate((c_minus_left, c_minus, c_minus_right), axis=0)
    gk1           = np.cumsum(ck)
    gk2           = np.cumsum(gk1)
    gk3           = np.cumsum(gk2)
    gk4           = np.cumsum(gk3)
    return gk1, gk2, gk3, gk4

# 1st-th antiderivative of signal
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.cdivision(True)
cdef AntiDerivative1st( int N, np.ndarray[double,ndim=1] InterpolationCoeffs, double new_indx ):

    cdef int k, Ak, Bk
    cdef double BSval
    cdef double out = 0.0
    cdef double[:] gk = InterpolationCoeffs[3:]

    if ( (new_indx>=0)&(new_indx<=N-1) ):
        Ak = <int>(ceil(new_indx-3))
        Bk = <int>(floor(new_indx+2))
        for k in range(Ak, Bk+1, 1):
            BSval = bspline4th(new_indx-<double>(k)-0.5)
            out   = out+gk[k+3]*BSval
        return out
    else:
        sys.exit( "Check the value of new_indx." )

# 2nd-th antiderivative of signal
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.cdivision(True)
cdef AntiDerivative2nd( int N, np.ndarray[double,ndim=1] InterpolationCoeffs, double new_indx ):

    cdef int k, Ak, Bk
    cdef double BSval
    cdef double out = 0.0
    cdef double[:] gk = InterpolationCoeffs[2:]

    if ( (new_indx>=0)&(new_indx<=N-1) ):
        Ak = <int>(ceil(new_indx-4))
        Bk = <int>(floor(new_indx+2))
        for k in range(Ak, Bk+1, 1):
            BSval = bspline5th(new_indx-<double>(k)-1.0)
            out   = out+gk[k+4]*BSval
        return out
    else:
        sys.exit( "Check the value of new_indx." )

# 3rd-th antiderivative of signal
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.cdivision(True)
cdef AntiDerivative3rd( int N, np.ndarray[double,ndim=1] InterpolationCoeffs, double new_indx ):

    cdef int k, Ak, Bk
    cdef double BSval
    cdef double out = 0.0
    cdef double[:] gk = InterpolationCoeffs[1:]

    if ( (new_indx>=0)&(new_indx<=N-1) ):
        Ak = <int>(ceil(new_indx-5))
        Bk = <int>(floor(new_indx+2))
        for k in range(Ak, Bk+1, 1):
            BSval = bspline6th(new_indx-<double>(k)-1.5)
            out   = out+gk[k+5]*BSval
        return out
    else:
        sys.exit( "Check the value of new_indx." )

# 4-th antiderivative of signal
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.cdivision(True)
cdef AntiDerivative4th( int N, np.ndarray[double,ndim=1] InterpolationCoeffs, double new_indx ):

    cdef int k, Ak, Bk
    cdef double BSval
    cdef double out = 0.0
    cdef double[:] gk = InterpolationCoeffs[:]

    if ( (new_indx>=0)&(new_indx<=N-1) ):
        Ak = <int>(ceil(new_indx-6))
        Bk = <int>(floor(new_indx+2))
        for k in range(Ak, Bk+1, 1):
            BSval = bspline7th(new_indx-<double>(k)-2.0)
            out   = out+gk[k+6]*BSval
        return out
    else:
        sys.exit( "Check the value of new_indx." )

# 4th Antiderivative of the signal with zero boundaries in the whole space
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.cdivision(True)
cdef OverallAntiDerivative4th( int N, np.ndarray[double,ndim=1] InterpolationCoeffs, 
                              double C1, double C2, double C3, double C4, double new_indx ):
    cdef double x  = new_indx
    cdef double x0 = <double>(N)
    cdef double y
    if (x<0.0):
        y = 0.0
    elif ((x>=0.0)&(x<x0-1.0)):
        y = AntiDerivative4th(N, InterpolationCoeffs, x)
    elif (x>=x0-1.0):
        y = C4+C3*(x-x0+1.0)+0.5*C2*(x-x0+1.0)**2+C1*((x-x0+1.0)**3)/6.0
    return y

# CWT of the one-dimensional signal
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.cdivision(True)
def ppCWT_cy( np.ndarray[double,ndim=1] freqs, np.ndarray[double,ndim=1] signal, 
              double Ls, np.ndarray[double,ndim=1] gamma, np.ndarray[double,ndim=2] Bj ):
    
    cwt_out     = np.zeros( (len(freqs),len(signal)), dtype=np.double)
    
    cdef int s, b, j
    cdef int Ns = len(freqs)
    cdef int N  = len(signal)
    cdef int Nj = len(gamma)
    cdef double C1, C2, C3, C4, F4, indx
    cdef double Dx         = Ls/<double>(N)
    cdef double[:] scales  = 2.0*freqs/sqrt(5.0)
    cdef double[:] sscales = Dx*2.0*freqs/sqrt(5.0)
    cdef double[:,:] cwt     = cwt_out

    if ( (Bj.shape[1]!=Nj)|(Bj.shape[0]!=Ns) ):
        sys.exit( "The length of Bj should be equal to that of gamma" )
    
    # Antiderivatives of signal
    gk1, gk2, gk3, gk4 = InterpCoeffs( signal )
    C1 = AntiDerivative1st( N, gk1, <double>(N)-1.0 )
    C2 = AntiDerivative2nd( N, gk2, <double>(N)-1.0 )
    C3 = AntiDerivative3rd( N, gk3, <double>(N)-1.0 )
    C4 = AntiDerivative4th( N, gk4, <double>(N)-1.0 )
 
    # Perform CWT
    for s in range(Ns):    # per scale
        for b in range(N): # per sampling point
            for j in range(Nj):
                indx     = <double>(b) - gamma[j]/sscales[s]
                F4       = OverallAntiDerivative4th( N, gk4, C1, C2, C3, C4, indx )
                cwt[s,b] = cwt[s,b] + Bj[s,j]*F4
            cwt[s,b] = Dx*sqrt(scales[s])*cwt[s,b]
    return cwt_out
```

**Question:**
To check the precision of the result of my code, I choose y=exp(-x^2) as the test signal since the CWT of it has an analytic formula. The code snippet is

```
import numpy as np
from ppCWT_cymod import ppCWT_cy,BjCoeff

# signal
N=2048
L=10.0
Dx = L/N
freqs = np.geomspace(2*np.pi/L, N*np.pi/L, num=256)
x = Dx*np.linspace(-N/2.0,N/2.0-1,N)
y = np.exp(-x**2)   

# perform CWT
gamma, Bj = BjCoeff( freqs, L, N, wavelet_name="gdw", half_support=13, Nums=34 )
cwt = ppCWT_cy( freqs, y, L, gamma, Bj )
```

The result is
[image]

Apparently, as the scale gets smaller and smaller (`freqs` larger), we see that wired noise arises on the right-hand side of the origin. After my examination, such a phenomenon has nothing to do with  `half_support`, `Nums`. At fixed length `L`, the noise is more severe as sampling number `N` becomes larger. **I really can't figure out the source of this noise. Can you help me?**

Comment: Just one small comment, always nice to have units on the axes!

Comment: @Jdip Thank you for your comment. The horizontal axis is the position, and the vertical axis is the wavelet frequency.

Comment: I figured! just a very general comment ;)

Comment: @Jdip Do you have any comments on the problem I've encountered?

Comment: FWIW the bounty wasn't automatically awarded. I get I've not fully answered your question but such detailed debugging is beyond this site in the first place. If a post is at least somewhat helpful and there aren't others, consider awarding manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Plot the frequency response of a bad wavelet. CWT is convolution, nothing can change that, hence there exists a `pf_scale` such that `out_scale = ifft(fft(x) * pf_scale)`. Also mind the [sampling grid](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/78551/50076).
2. Prefer the unit impulse for debugging: `x = zeros(N); x[N//2] = 1`. With zero-padding and no unpadding (or just no padding), it will yield `ifft(pf_scale)` for all `scale`.
3. Test linearity: `cwt(x1) + cwt(x2) == cwt(x1 + x2)`. If this fails, that's a critical flaw, and the problem is beyond wavelets: the algo isn't doing convolution. Pick `x1=x2=zeros(N); x1[N//4]=1; x2[-N//4]=1`.
4. Code in Python first so it's easier to debug interactively.

A plot of `pf_scale` will inevitably reveal problematic behavior, which then must be traced through the steps involved in computing it. Isolate the code for wavelet generation and plot the wavelet at every step:

```
freqs = # ...
plot(freqs)
wav0 = func0(freqs, param0, param1)
plot(wav0)
wav1 = func1(wav0, param2)
plot(wav1)
# ...
plot(freqs)
# ...
pf_scale = func9(wav8)
```

then compare against a well-behaved `pf_scale`. Pay attention to how `scale` affects each step, especially non-smooth and precision-sensitive functions. I see `BjCoeff` divides by `scales`.

It's possible (and appears to be the case) that the algo doesn't use convolution in a direct form. Again, your task is to rewrite the algorithm *until it does*. So if the wavelet used by the algo is `pf_scale_algo`, then rewrite and track effects on frequency, `pf_scale_algo -> pf_scale_revised0 -> pf_scale_revised1 -> ...` until `-> pf_scale`. Worst case, visual comparison should aid considerably.