# Why does a signal with constant frequency have spots that changes colors at a specific value of scale (and so frequency) in the scalogram?

Tags: python, wavelet, time-frequency, cwt, pywavelets

I am studying the Wavelet transform and I am considering this example that I took from [PyWavelets documentation](https://pywavelets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/cwt.html#continuous-wavelet-families). The signal in time domain has the following shape:

[image]

Till the value of zero on the horizontal axis we have a signal with a constant frequency. So I would expect the scalogram to have something like a constant (both in color and in dimension) horizontal stripe at a specific value of the scale (or period or frequency or whatever you want to put on the y axis of the scalogram) till the zero value, while instead it has like vertical stripes that alternate their colors from the extreme violet color to the extreme green. Why ?! This is the image:

[image]

From a scalogram like this, I would expect a signal that changes frequencies because the changing of colors means that changing of values of wavelets coefficients and so the changing of similarity between the wavelet and the input signal (since the operation that is done is the convolution between the wavelet and the data). High similarity should mean high coefficients (so green color) while low similarity means low values of coefficients (so violet colors); if the colors changes means that the similarity changes and so also the shape of the signal changes and thus also the frequency. Is this right ? What am I missing ?

Any suggestion would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**EDITI**:I appreciate the suggestions in the comments below my post but since there has not been an answer to my post and my question has not been closed, I want to share with you that I found a clear explanation in this nice video [Wavelets: a mathematical microscope](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jnxqHcObNK4&t=1320s). As Ash pointed out, one should plot the magnitude of a *complex* wavelet and so one has to consider the convolution with both the real and imaginary part of the wavelet. Hence by following this procedure, *I obtain the plot as I expected it to be but with still one problem*: the red bar that should be in correspondence of scale value equal to 30 and the distortions (that correspond to signal changing in frequency) should go from 30 to lower scales, in my case is inverted. Why ?

[image]

Here is the Python code that I used:

```
time = np.linspace(-1, 1, 200, endpoint=False)
signal  = np.cos(2 * np.pi * 7 * time) + np.real(np.exp(-7*(time-0.4)**2)*np.exp(1j*2*np.pi*2*(time-0.4)))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 5))
ax.plot(time,signal)
sns.despine(fig, bottom=False, left=False)
plt.show()

scales = np.arange(1,31)
ylabel = 'Period'
xlabel = 'Time'

waveletname='cgau2'
coef, freqs=pywt.cwt(signal, scales, waveletname)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 2))
contourf_ = ax.contourf(time, scales, np.abs(coef), cmap=plt.cm.Reds)#extend='both',
ax.set_title('Wavelet Transform of Signal (${}$)'.format(waveletname), fontsize=20)
ax.set_ylabel('Scales', fontsize=14)
ax.set_xlabel('Time (s)', fontsize=14)
fig.colorbar(contourf_)
plt.show()
```

**EDITII**:

```
#Time domain signal
time = np.linspace(-1, 1, 200, endpoint=False)
signal  = np.cos(2 * np.pi * 7 * time) + np.real(np.exp(-7*(time-0.4)**2)*np.exp(1j*2*np.pi*2*(time-0.4)))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 5))
ax.plot(time,signal)
sns.despine(fig, bottom=False, left=False)
plt.show()

#Setting parameters for Continous Wavelet Transform
scales = np.arange(1,31)
waveletname='cgau2'
coef, freqs=pywt.cwt(signal, scales, waveletname)



#contourf

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 2))
contourf_ = ax.contourf(time, scales, np.abs(coef), cmap=plt.cm.Reds)#extend='both',
ax.set_title('Wavelet Transform of Signal (${}$)'.format(waveletname), fontsize=20)
ax.set_ylabel('Scales', fontsize=14)
ax.set_xlabel('Time (s)', fontsize=14)
fig.colorbar(contourf_)
plt.show()



#matshow
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 5))
matshow_ = ax.matshow(np.abs(coef), extent=[-1, 1, 1, 31], aspect = 'auto', cmap='Reds',
                      vmax=abs(coef).max(), vmin=0) 
fig.colorbar(matshow_)
plt.gca().xaxis.tick_bottom() # it puts x axis from top to bottom of figure.
loc = plticker.MultipleLocator(base=0.25)  # this locator puts ticks at regular intervals
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)
ax.set_title('Wavelet Transform of Signal (${}$)'.format(waveletname), fontsize=20)
ax.set_ylabel('Scales', fontsize=15)
ax.set_xlabel('Time', fontsize=15)
plt.show() 



#imshow
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 5))
imshow_ = plt.imshow(np.abs(coef), extent=[-1, 1, 1, 31], cmap='Reds', aspect='auto',
           vmax=abs(coef).max(), vmin=0)  
fig.colorbar(imshow_)
ax.set_title('Wavelet Transform of Signal (${}$)'.format(waveletname), fontsize=20)
ax.set_ylabel('Scales', fontsize=15)
ax.set_xlabel('Time', fontsize=15)
plt.show()
```

This is the plot using `matshow` or `imshow`.

[image]

Comment: Try plotting the magnitude instead of just the real or imaginary part.

Comment: Ash is correct, I also recommend [against](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/78551/50076) pywt in favor of ssqueezepy, though I'm the author. This specific example is fine in pywt.

Comment: @Ash I edited the post. I followed your advice but I have still problems... If you can give further hints please :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Re: real part

There are oscillations because that's what the wavelet transform is - a decomposition into zero-mean, localized oscillations. CWT is convolution (rather, cross-correlation) of signal with wavelets, and you're taking the real part of this result: top animation [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/78513/50076) may help. With analytic or real wavelets, the CWT also nicely interprets as "redistributing" the signal over a 2D plane, with each oscillatory component in its proper slot, per the [one-integral inverse](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/76239/50076).

`abs` gives intensity, which interprets as amplitude but only with *analytic* wavelets, which `cgau2` isn't, and is why `b` is over-represented.

#### Re: wrong scales

The red plot is correct, the green-purple one isn't. Lower scale $\Leftrightarrow$ higher frequency. Let's plot `sig`:

[image]

- Blue is a pure sine: constant frequency over time, so a horizontal bar in time-freq
- Orange is a Gaussian-windowed sine: constant frequency but localized in time, so a "lump" in time-freq

Clearly, orange is lower in frequency, hence "resonates" with greater scale. `pywt`'s example is fixed via `extent=[-1, 1, 31, 1]` (I originally ignored this). For best results, apply a wavelet with high time resolution:

[image]

Note the sine is around frequency=7, matching `np.cos(2 * np.pi * 7 * t)`.

```py
import numpy as np
from ssqueezepy import cwt, Wavelet
from ssqueezepy.experimental import scale_to_freq
from ssqueezepy.visuals import imshow

t = np.linspace(-1, 1, 200, endpoint=False)
sig = (np.cos(2 * np.pi * 7 * t) +
       np.real(np.exp(-7*(t-0.4)**2)*np.exp(1j*2*np.pi*2*(t-0.4))))

wavelet = Wavelet(('gmw', {'beta': 4}))
Wx, scales = cwt(sig, wavelet, padtype='zero')

freqs = scale_to_freq(scales, wavelet, N=len(sig), fs=1/(t[1] - t[0]))
imshow(Wx, abs=1, yticks=freqs,  xticks=t,
       xlabel="time [sec]", ylabel="frequency [Hz]")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Your module is really powerfull and intuitive. One question related to this: how to know the list of wavelets available with *ssqueezepy* ? And lastly, (which was in truth the original question), why by using *contourf* the resulting image is opposite to what it should be ?

Comment: @User `ssqueezepy.wavs()`, code in `wavelets.py`. Also worth noting `ssqueezepy.Wavelet().info()`. To your question, again, the red image is correct; the green-purple one is incorrect because the y-axis is scales and yet `a` ends up at a higher scale than `b`.

Comment: Sorry maybe I have to think better about it but also in your graph the "distortion" is at lower frequencies...

Comment: @User Yes, that's `b`, orange: less wiggles = lower frequency. It's also lower frequency (higher scale) in your `conftour`. Your plots are "flipped" relative to mine because they're greater scale from bottom to top, whereas mine are greater frequency.

Comment: you are right... sorry again. However now my concern is why taking only the real part of a wavelet leads to wrong frequency values ? And if I do the same plot with matshow and imshow, it is the same as the green-purple from the point of view of frequencies values.

Comment: I have edited the post.

Comment: Ok I discovered that it was because of *extent*... removing it, all results are the same as your plot. Thank you very much !

Comment: @User Valid question concerning real part, updated. Also note `scales` in `contourf` flips the plot.

Comment: Great answer, +1.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon I have  a question about colors. Red corresponds to high overlapping between the wavelet and the signal while blue is no overlap ? What is the scale of colors ? Where is documentation about this particular that I ask ? I apologize for further question.

Comment: @User No problem, I appreciate your well-researched question. I'll try to get around to it.