# Inverse continuous wavelet transform, how to obtain fluctuations at a given scale with ssqueezepy?

Tags: signal-analysis, python, time-frequency, cwt, ssqueezepy

How can I obtain the fluctuations of a timeseries at a specific scale using the ssqueezepy library for inverse continuous wavelet transform (ICWT)?

I have a minimum reproducible example that uses the squezepy library to perform the continuous wavelet transform (CWT) and estimate the ICWT. However, what I would like to do is to perform the ICWT for a particular scale and return the fluctuations of the timeseries corresponding to that scale. Can someone help me with this problem?

```
import numpy as np


import ssqueezepy
def PSD_cwt_ssqueezepy(x, y, z, dt, nv =16, scales='log-piecewise', wavelet=None, wname=None, l1_norm=False, est_PSD=False):
    """
    Method to calculate the wavelet coefficients and  power spectral density using wavelet method.
    Parameters
    ----------
    x,y,z: array-like
        the components of the field to apply wavelet tranform
    dt: float
        the sampling time of the timeseries
        
    scales: str['log', 'log-piecewise', 'linear', 'log:maximal', ...]
                / np.ndarray
            CWT scales.
    Returns
    -------
    W_x, W_y, W_zz: array-like
        component coeficients of th wavelet tranform
    freq : list
        Frequency of the corresponding psd points.
    psd : list
        Power Spectral Density of the signal.
    scales : list
        The scales at which wavelet was estimated
    """
    
    if wavelet is None:
        wavelet    = ssqueezepy.Wavelet(('morlet', {'mu': 13.4}))
    else:
        wavelet    = ssqueezepy.Wavelet((wname, {'mu': 13.4}))  
        
    if  scales is  None:
        scales = 'log-piecewise'

    # Estimate sampling frequency
    fs         = 1/dt
    # Estimate wavelet coefficients
    Wx, scales = ssqueezepy.cwt(x, wavelet, scales, fs, l1_norm=l1_norm, nv=nv)
    Wy, _      = ssqueezepy.cwt(y, wavelet, scales, fs, l1_norm=l1_norm, nv=nv)
    Wz, _      = ssqueezepy.cwt(z, wavelet, scales, fs, l1_norm=l1_norm, nv=nv)
    
    # Estimate corresponding frequencies
    freqs      = ssqueezepy.experimental.scale_to_freq(scales, wavelet, len(x), fs)
    
    if est_PSD:
        # Estimate trace powers pectral density
        PSD = (np.nanmean(np.abs(Wx)**2, axis=1) + np.nanmean(np.abs(Wy)**2, axis=1) + np.nanmean(np.abs(Wz)**2, axis=1)   )*( 2*dt)
    else:
        PSD = None
    
    return Wx, Wy, Wz, freqs, PSD, scales, wavelet


# Parameters
N       = 20000
dt      = 1
nv      =  16
scales  ='log-piecewise'
wavelet = None
wname   = None 
l1_norm = False 
est_PSD = False

#Create a signal forexample
sig = np.sin(np.linspace(0,  5*np.pi, N))+np.random.rand(N)


# Do the CWT analysis to obtain wavelet coeeficients
Wx, Wy, Wz, freqs, PSD, scales,wavelet = PSD_cwt_ssqueezepy(sig, sig, sig, dt, nv , scales, wavelet, wname, l1_norm, est_PSD)

# Obtain ICWT for one of the components Wx

rec_signal = ssqueezepy.icwt(Wx, 
                  wavelet, 
                  scales,
                  nv,
                  l1_norm)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per how the one-integral inverse works, this is as simple as `Wx[scale_idx].real`, within a scaling. However it's probably not what you want.

The CWT is inherently imperfectly localized in both time and frequency, so any result that desires said result must be handled carefully. [Relevant article](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/76371/50076). If you really want contents "at" a time or frequency, you need instantaneous methods, like [synchrosqueezing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/71399/50076).

If instead what you want is `icwt` of an individual signal *component*, that's a well-defined task. Here `scale_idx` may vary with time, so specifying is non-trivial - refer to [this post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/83742/50076), which contains unfinished code of a tool I made to facilitate manual extraction. There's also [`ssqueezepy.extract_ridges`](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/ssqueezepy/blob/master/examples/extracting_ridges.py).

Lastly, `ssqueezepy` doesn't have a built-in for inverting CWT over specific scales vs time, but we can simply use `issq_cwt`, and for most part the result will be within a constant of the true result. You could try combining the right parts of `issq_cwt` (`_invert_components`) and `icwt` to improve the results. *But*, if you want to invert over *entire* scales (not vs time), it's as simple as passing in `Wx[i0:i1]` and `scales[i0:i1]` - just careful with `scales='log-piecewise'`, pass in only the log or linear portion at a time to avoid edge cases (use `idx = logscale_transition_idx(scales)` to get where the transition happens).

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I am not exactly sure i understand your answr. What you suggest is that If I wanted to get the fluctuations at a given scale I could do this using ssq_cwt and then issq_cwt on Wx[scale_idx].real?     What I am intersted in getting is several timeseries. Each corresponding to a given scale of the CWT( or ssq_CWT) that results from taking the  ICWT (or issq_cwt ). Is this even possible?

Comment: @Jokerp `Wx[scale_idx].real` _are_ the fluctuations. Equals. If scale of interest is `5`, and `scales[20] == 5`, then `Wx[20].real` is what you need. For several scales at once, we'd do e.g. `icwt(Wx[5:30], scales[5:30])`, that returns the combined signal.

Comment: Isnt Wx[scale_idx].real the fluctuation in k space? What I meant is after obtaing the wavelet coefficients ICWT them at each scale to get the fluctuation in time. Is this what you meant?

Comment: @Jokerp The coefficient is the inverse, that's the beauty of satisfying the one-integral inverse criteria in the forward transform. It's what I describe on top [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/85639/50076). Don't know what you mean by "k space".

Comment: Thank you so much for your responses. I see! So what you say is that there is two things to consider. In case i want the fluctuations as function of time for a given scale I could just Wx[scale_idx].real, however, 1) When using CWT the fluctuations would beimperfectly localized in time 2) I would need to normalize by a costant to get the desired result?    What you also suggest is that issq_cwt would amend for the first issue but not the second  one? Would you mind providin a MRE to do what you suggested using issq_cwt?

Comment: That's a bit much back & forths, so briefly. Yes & yes 1 & 2. `issq_cwt` is for inverting `ssq_cwt`, not `cwt`, but it has `_invert_components`. It solves neither 1 nor 2 with `cwt`, but `icwt` solves 2 for `cwt`. `ssq_cwt` solves 1 and 2, but 1 just partially. I suggest reading through some code and experimenting with signals to better understand what's happening. -- Also I should mention that this "direct inversion" only works with `l1_norm=True` (default).