# Python's equivalent of MATLAB's cwtfilterbank

Tags: matlab, python, wavelet, cwt, pywavelets

I am learning signal processing and would like to know what's the python equivalent of matlab's [cwtfilterbank](https://www.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/cwtfilterbank.html).

I looked through `pywt` but did not find anything.

Some background information: I would like to process audio files with a CWT filter bank, where the wavelet filters are logarithmically spaced bandpass filters.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

[Avoid](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/86069/50076) PyWavelets and scipy. [ssqueezepy](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/ssqueezepy)'s (disclaimer, am author) `scales='auto'` is motivated similar to MATLAB's `cwtfilterbank`, and wavelets can be cached, inspected, and reused.

[image]

```py
import numpy as np
from ssqueezepy import Wavelet, cwt
from ssqueezepy.utils import make_scales, cwt_scalebounds
from ssqueezepy.visuals import plot, imshow

# configure
signal_length = 4096
wavelet = Wavelet('morlet')

# make scales
min_scale, max_scale = cwt_scalebounds(wavelet, signal_length)
scales = make_scales(signal_length, scaletype='log', nv=8,
                     min_scale=min_scale, max_scale=max_scale)
# make filterbank
fbank = wavelet(scale=scales)

# take CWT
np.random.seed(0)
x = np.random.randn(signal_length)
Wx, _ = cwt(x, wavelet, scales=scales)

# visualize
plot(fbank.T, show=1, title="CWT filterbank")
imshow(Wx, title="|CWT(x)|", abs=1)
```

Comment: You did a great work on Wavelets. How come you fell into them so much? What was your motivation?

Comment: Cause I'm insane. And there's much more where that came from, soon, but I'm too busy beating people over the head on stonk exchange. May tell the rest another day.

Comment: Moderately insane people are my kind of people. Please do share more. Enjoy the ride.